# python 3.7 error in using numbers(value) from dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
favorite_numbers = {
                     'john': 33,
                     'mona':   22,
                     'emma':  11,
                     'harvey':    2,
                     'patrick':  5,                 
                     }
 
 print(
       favorite_numbers['john'].title() + "'s favorite number is" 
        " " + str(favorite_numbers['john']) + "."
       )

#'int' object has no attribute 'title' eroor is shown
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow - please review the [guidelines on how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - this will help you to get useful answers to your question

Answer (score 0):

So what you are doing when you type, `favorite_numbers['john']` is the number 33 gets returned, and you are trying to use the `.title()` function on the number 33. Numbers cannot be capital or lowercase, they are numbers, so it gives you an error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you got `favorite_numbers['john'].title()` from, but it's not going to do what you think it should do. Just go with:

`print("john" + "'s favorite number is " + str(favorite_numbers['john']) + ".")`

Or

```
person = "john"
print(person + "'s favorite number is " + str(favorite_numbers[person]) + ".")
```

Answer (score 0):

Python's f-strings let you put namespace aware formatting directives in a string. For example, `f"{foo}"` prints whatever is in `foo`. This is frequently a more clear way to format a string that using addition. In your example, you already know that you want John's favorite number, so you can

```
print("John's favorite number is {favorite_numbers['john']}.")
```

If you want to use the name in a variable, then it can be part of the f-string too.

```
>>> for name, num in favorite_numbers.items():
...     print(f"{name.title()}'s favorite number is {num}")
... 
John's favorite number is 33
Mona's favorite number is 22
Emma's favorite number is 11
Harvey's favorite number is 2
Patrick's favorite number is 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Your using title with an integer, i think you meant to use it on the key instead, i dont know any way to get specificly 1 key from a dictionary so do this:

```
print(f"John's favorite number is {favorite_numbers[john]}")
```

or

```
print("John's favorite number is ", favorite_numbers[john])
```

or

```
print("John's favorite number is " + favorite_numbers[john])
```